# Joomla Error: 0 DateTime::__construct() on failed logins and editing existing articles/modules

Tags: joomla, joomla3.1

Yesterday, I noticed failed log in attempts on my site were throwing the user to the site error page instead of the "aww, we're sorry, your username/password is incorrect," page.
With a little investigation on my site this error happens on the backend whenever I try to edit modules or articles that already exist. I can create new module instances and articles.
Here's the error,

```
Error: 0 DateTime::__construct() [datetime.--construct]: Failed to parse time string (jerror) at position 0 (j): The timezone could not be found in the database
```

I looked around on the internet and found a handful of similar error, though more often than not it was an error 500 and not the error 0 I got. I followed their instructions anyway.

- make sure files are writable. [screen](https://www.dropbox.com/s/pczfmxuz3ipw2mb/Screenshot-2013-06-26-08.43.15.png)
- make sure you have a timezone set in your php.ini
- Add -> suPHP_ConfigPath /home/YOURNAME/public_html to my .htaccess

PHP 5.3.19
Apache
Joomla! 3.1.1 Stable [ Ember ] 26-April-2013 14:00 GMT

[Joomla Forum Post Assistant](http://forum.joomla.org/viewtopic.php?f=706&t=807834#p3048666)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

...a little embarrassing, my log path pointed to a folder that didn't exist.
I blindly trusted joomla when it told me my error path was writable. eff me, right?

Comment: in joomla's defense, I was pointing the log to a "writable" file but joomla wasn't looking for a writable file, it wanted a folder... reading is *important*.